# Using UTM with geodjango

Tags: python, django, geodjango, gdal, geos

I'm looking into using the [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) coordinate system with geodjango.
And I can't figure out how to get the data in properly.

I've been browsing the documentation and it seems that the "[GEOSGeometry(geo_input, srid=None)](http://geodjango.org/docs/geos.html#geosgeometry-geo-input-srid-none)" or "[OGRGeometry](http://geodjango.org/docs/gdal.html?highlight=convertion#ogrgeometry)" could be used with an EWKT, but I can't figure out how to format the data.

It looks like the UTM [SRID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID) is: 2029

From the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) the format is written like this:

[*UTMZone*][*N or S*] [*easting*] [*northing*]

*17N 630084 4833438*

So I tried the following with no luck:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
>>> pnt = GEOSGeometry('SRID=2029;POINT(17N 630084 4833438)')
GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Expected number but encountered word: '17N'
>>>
>>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import OGRGeometry
>>> pnt = OGRGeometry('SRID=2029;POINT(17N 630084 4833438)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\geometries.py", line 106, in __init__
    ogr_t = OGRGeomType(geom_input)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\geomtype.py", line 31, in __init__
    raise OGRException('Invalid OGR String Type "%s"' % type_input)
django.contrib.gis.gdal.error.OGRException: Invalid OGR String Type "srid=2029;point(17n 630084 4833438)"
```

Are there any example available to show how this is done?

May be I should just do any necessary calulations in UTM and convert to decimal degrees?
In this case does GEOS or other tools in geodjango provide convertion utitilites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The UTM zone (17N) is already specified by the spatial reference system  -- [SRID 2029](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2029/), so you don't need to include it in the WKT you pass to the `GEOSGeometry` constructor.

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
>>> pnt = GEOSGeometry('SRID=2029;POINT(630084 4833438)')
>>> (pnt.x, pnt.y)
(630084.0, 4833438.0)
>>> pnt.srid
2029
```

Then, for example:

```
>>> pnt.transform(4326)   # Transform to WGS84
>>> (pnt.x, pnt.y)
(-79.387137066054038, 43.644504290860461)
>>> pnt.srid
4326
```

Comment: I would add that geometry given in form of Well-Known-Text, either OGC WKT or PostGIS/GEOS-specific format of Extended WKT, components given between parenthesis () after geometry tag, should only specify coordinates: X Y, optionally Z and M dimensions. No other exotic elements are allowed, so 17N is an invalid token. In case of EWKT, spatial reference system can be given using dedicated specifier SRID.